# Cable from charging port on Samsung S4 to full HDMI in car

Tags: hdmi, mhl

I bought new Honda Civic 2015 and could not afford the model with GPS so dealer told me no problem, just hook up the android phone to the HDMI cable and use the phone GPS. I need to know

1. If the normal charging cable (see attached) is a micro cable
2. If so, is the micro cable to full HDMI cable called MHL

   [eBay micro to full HDMI](http://www.ebay.com/itm/MHL-Micro-USB-to-HDMI-1080P-HDTV-Cable-Adapter-for-Samsung-Galaxy-S5-Note-3-III-/261499577168?hash=item3ce296e350:g:iDEAAOSwVL1WEloe)
3. If the cable available on eBay work (see the website) and
4. Will my Sygic app work on my video screen in the car.

[image: Micro cable??]

Answer (score 1):

1. **Yes** that is Micro USB
2. **Yes** the Micro Cable to HDMI that you need is MHL
3. **Strong Maybe** that cable gets good reviews, so seems promising
4. **Yes** the Sygic app will work fine.